# asp.net error as "Too many characters in character literal"

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am calling a javascript on index change of a DropDownList, i do as follows

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="toggleVisibility('Button1');">
```

I get the error during compiling as for the above line of code

```
Too many characters in character literal
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnSelectedIndexChanged` is a server side event, <del>you need to set `OnClientClick` instead and set AutoPostBack="false" if your intention is to toggle visibility on client side</del>

For the server side

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="toggleVisibility">

protected object toggleVisibility(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button1.Visible = !Button1.Visible;
}
```

So for the events you need to use the method name which has a specific signature, defined by the event type. Here is `object sender, EventArgs e`

**Edit**

DropDownList has no property called OnClientClick, so you need to add it in codebehind

```
DropDownList1.Attributes.Add("onchange","toggleVisibility('Button1');");
```